# SwiftUI - Selecting the correct View type based on API field

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui

Apologies if this question is a bit abstract, but here it goes:

An API returns a list of resources comprised of a couple simple fields. One of the fields ("view-id" in the example), tells the client which SwiftUI `View` to use when rendering the data.

```
[
  {
    "title": "Example Title"
    "image": "https://www.example.com/some/image.png"
    "view-id": "text-row" // tells the client to use, say, `TextRowView`
  },
  {
    "title": "A Second Title"
    "image": "https://www.example.com/some/other/image.png"
    "view-id": "image-row" // tells the client to use, say, `ImageRowView`
  }
]
```

My goal is to find a scalable way to allow for the `View` type to be selected at runtime based on `view-id` in the API.

In my attempt to solve this, I've defined the following protocol to describe a type that can create the view

```
protocol MyViewBuilder {
    
    associatedtype Content: View
    
    func buildView(data: Data) -> Content
}

/// concrete implementation of a `MyViewBuilder`
struct MyExampleViewBuilder {
    
    func buildView(data: Data) -> Text {
        Text(data.string)
    }
}
```

I've defined the following protocol to map the 'view-id' from the API to a specific type of view:

```
protocol MyViewDescriptor {

    associatedtype Content: View
    
    var id: String { get }
}

/// concrete implementation for a `MyViewDescriptor`
struct MyExampleDescriptor {

    associatedtype Content: Text
    
    var id: String = "text-row"
}
```

Now, I've build a type that allows for registering & accessing these pieces like so:

```
class MyGlueCode: MyViewBuilder {
    func register<D, B>(_ descriptor: D, viewBuilder: B) where D: MyViewDescriptor,
                                                                   B: MyViewBuilder,
                                                                   D.Content == B.Content {...}


    func buildView<D, Content>(descriptor: D, data: Data) -> Content where D: MyViewDescriptor, Content == D.Content { ... }

    
}
```

Now the above code can be made to work with a little type erasing, but where I am struggling is how to preserve / generate the 'descriptor' argument for `buildView(descriptor:data:)`. But I cannot devise a way to make this bit direct at the call site, where ideally I can do something simple like

```
ForEach(data) { 
   SomeClass().view(for: $0)
}
```

I am stuck :( help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
enum ViewType: String {
    case text = "text-row"
    case image = "image-row"

    static func view(for data: Data) -> some View {
        let type = Self(rawValue: data.viewId)

        return Group {
            if type == nil {
                Text("Unsupported View Type")
            } else if type == .text {
                TexDataView(data: data)
            } else if type == .image {
                ImageDataView(data: data)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemoDataView: View {
    let data: Data
    var body: some View {
        ViewType.view(for: data)
    }
}
```

assuming replicated

```
struct Data {
    let title: String
    let image: String
    let viewId: String
}
```